# Limit of a sequence with ln.

Tags: limits

even though it's not actually a homework rather than some training for myself, I'm posting it with tag "Homework":

$ \ln(x)^4 $ means: $ \left( \ln (x) \right)^4 $

What is $\lim_{x\to 0} (x^a \cdot \ln(x)^4)$ ? I am not allowed to use L-Hospital.

I tried writing it like:

$\lim_{x\to 0} (x^a \cdot ln(x)^4) = \lim_{x \to 0} (e^{a\cdot \ln(x)} * e^{\ln(\ln(x)^4)}) = \lim_{x \to 0} (e^{a\cdot \ln(x) + \ln(\ln(x)^4})$ ... Well, I'm really not sure whether I made the right choice(s) ;-(

Comment: Do you mean $\ln(x^4)$ or $(\ln x)^4$.

Comment: Hello! I Mean $(ln x)^4 $ [it's written as $ln(x)^4 $and means ln(x)*ln(x)*ln(x)*ln(x) ]

Comment: Can you use $\lim_{x\to0}x\ln x=0$?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not ;/

Comment: Use $\large x = {\rm e}^{-z}$.

Answer (score 1):

In the case when $a\le0$, the computation is easy, so we can assume $a>0$.
One can simplify the computation by considering first
$$
\lim_{x\to0}x^b\ln x
$$
where $b=a/4$. If we set $\ln x=-t$, we have $x^b=e^{-bt}$ and the limit becomes
$$
-\lim_{t\to\infty}te^{-bt}=
-\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{e^{bt}}=-\frac{1}{b}\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{bt}{e^{bt}}
=-\frac{1}{b}\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u}{e^u}.
$$
This is a known limit.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\lim_{x \to 0}\bracks{x^{a}\ln^{4}\pars{x}}}
=
\lim_{x \to \infty}\bracks{\expo{-ax}x^{4}}
=\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{lcl}
+\infty & \mbox{if} & a \leq 0
\\[2mm]
0 & \mbox{if} & a > 0
\end{array}\right.}
$$